# How do you debug an existing MVC project on a mac/apple with "Visual Studio Code"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-code, kestrel-http-server

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC project using Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine.

I need to coordinate with a designer who uses Mac exclusively which means using VS Code.

Naturally, she needs to be able to do simple things like open a project, edit the CSS/HTML and a bit of JS, and launch it in a browser to see how the changes look and behave. Opening and editing is no problem but this last part is the killer.

I got Visual Studio Code, Mono, and DNX installed and she can open the project and edit the code but when I open the command palate and try to enter the Kestrel commands as seen on tutorials like [this example](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html), the application doesn't seem to recognize any commands. The dnu restore command also doesn't seem to work. Googling around I found some sites with instructions to use the Mac Termial which yielded zero results (maybe because I've never touched a Mac terminal).

I'm a real Mac dummy but as far as I can tell, that's not the issue at hand. The issue seems to be that the project isn't properly configured to use Kestrel. In fact, I don't see a "project.json" file, nor a "Startup.CS", both of which I suspect are needed.

If I'm on the right track, please either outline how to set up the project.json and Startup.CS in an existing MVC project developed on VS2015, or point me to a source of info.

If I'm not, what do I need to do to get the darn thing to launch in a browser?

Comment: I suspect you are running MVC4 instead of MVC5?

Comment: Yeah MVC4... starting to think my only good option is to get a discounted Windows 10 license and run VS in a Windows VM on her Mac. Seems like an overly complicated solution though.